# php web crawler breaks, running out of time limit?

Tags: php, facebook, apache, web-crawler

I am writing a PHP Web Application to do statistics on multiple(actually a long list of) Facebook pages.  I set up the crawler to fetch data for all of the pages from Facebook every day so the data is always updated in the local databases.

The problem is, sometimes the crawler breaks unexpectedly. The reasons I am guessing are:
1) running out the Server's time limit
2) waiting for too long for data without any response and get killed

Do you have any suggestions to solve this problem?  Thanks a lot!!

Comment: “Stop _guessing_, start __debugging__.”

Comment: Do you have any errors in your log file? Changing stuff before you know the root cause is a *bad* idea

Answer (score 1):

You should start by increasing the max_execution_time variable in php.ini. See if that solves your problem. If the problem is with Facebook or any other web server outside of your control, there's not much you can do.

*Disclaimer: This is all assuming your code is valid and doesn't find itself in some infinite loop on occasion...

Answer (score 0):

Try to add

```
set_time_limit (0);
```

in the beginning of your script.